# Azure: Can't deploy to staging

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Suddenly since a couple of days ago I cannot deploy to my Azure cloud service to the staging environment. Deployment fails with:

> Allocation failed; unable to satisfy constraints in request. The requested new service deployment is bound to an Affinity Group, or it targets a Virtual Network, or there is an existing deployment under this hosted service. Any of these conditions constrains the new deployment to specific Azure resources. Please retry later or try reducing the VM size or number of role instances. Alternatively, if possible, remove the aforementioned constraints or try deploying to a different region.

I do have my database virtual machine, my web-/workerroles and my Azure Storage account in the same affinity group talking to each other via a virtual network and I believe it is important to keep it that way to minimize network latency. Has anyone experienced this problem and could you solve it without getting rid of the affinity group?